# How to set image path of specific ityem in ListView?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `ListView` of `Button` elements like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding NumberOfItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
    <ListViewItem >
         <Button Name="test" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="10" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent" Command="{Binding DataContext.TestCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}">
                                    <Button.Template>
                                        <ControlTemplate>
                                            <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" x:Name="bg">
                                                <Image Source="{Binding DataContext.Test_ImagePath, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Button.Template>
         </Button>
    </ListViewItem >
</ListView>
```

My goal is to have button's image to toggle between two image paths on button click. It works, but the problem is that all the buttons in the list change the image path on some button click. I want only the one that is clicked to change the image path. I tried using `CommandTarget` property like this:

```
CommandTarget="{Binding DataContext.Listview.SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListViewItem}}
```

but it didn't heplp.

Just to mention that I use MVVM.

How to solve this?

Comment: What objects does the ItemsSource `NumberOfItems` contain?

Comment: It is just integers for now, but I can change it to anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using MVVM, I suppose you could wrap your models (As you said, integers for now) with a wrapper like this:

```
public class ToggleableWrapper<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private bool toggled;

    public ToggleableWrapper(T item){
        this.Item = item;
        this.ClickCommand = new RelayCommand(() => this.Toggled = !this.Toggled);
    }

    public T Item {get;}
    public ICommand ClickCommand {get;}

    public bool Toggled {
        get { return this.toggled; }
        set { 
            this.toggled = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.Toggled));
        }
    }

    //Property changed implementation...
}
```

So your `NumberOfItems` collection could look like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<ToggleableWrapper<int>> NumberOfItems {get;}
```

Now you need a ValueConverter which will convert the toggled boolean to your image. Call it `ToggledToImageConverter`
You can implement it accordingly and make it a resource somewhere.

Now your ListView looks like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding NumberOfItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Name="test" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="10" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent" Command="{Binding ClickCommand}">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" x:Name="bg">
                            <Image Source="{Binding Toggled, Converter={StaticResouce ToggledToImageConverter}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
             </Button>
         <DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

So when you click the button, the bool is toggled, which will then toggle the image using the ValueConverter.